# Why is my child class constructor not being called?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

It's a real mystery. I created a base class:

#### Generator.h

```
class Generator
{
public:
    Generator(int);
    Generator();
    virtual ~Generator() {};
    //more virtual stuff follows
    ...
};
```

#### Generator.cpp

```
Generator::Generator()
{
     //nothing to do here
}
```

Then I created a child class:

#### LoopGenerator.h

```
class LoopGenerator : public Generator
{
public:
    LoopGenerator();
    ~LoopGenerator();
    virtual void add(RandomStripe&);
    ///more stuff follows
    ...
protected:
    unsigned int pointer;
    std::vector<Generator*> stripes;
};
```

#### LoopGenerator.cpp

```
LoopGenerator::LoopGenerator()
{
    pointer = 0;
    stripes = vector<Generator*>();
}
void LoopGenerator::add(Generator* stripe)
{
    stripes.push_back(stripe);
}
```

I then try to create the `LoopGenerator` instance:

#### main.cpp

```
LoopGenerator gen = LoopGenerator();
gen.add(RandomStripe((unsigned int)seedval, 5,10, 231,231, 0,255, 0,255));
```

You can see I called a method `.add`. The `.add` method **is called** but the constructor isn't. I actually thought `LoopGenerator()` is a constructor call!

This is what happens with breakpoint on the constructor:

[image: child constructor not being called]

Comment: Are you sure it's not being called? Try shoving a print statement in there to verify. Depending on the optimisation level, the compiler could be trying to inline the construction of `gen`.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you shouldn't try programming Java in C++ (or why are there so many raw pointers, and mis-use of ctors?), from what I see the IDE-proposed "compiler optimization" might be the cause. But it's hard to say without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Deduplicator Could you elaborate? What mis-use of constructor? Also what exactly is done "like java" here?

Comment: @TomášZato: This Java-esque construct: `stripes = vector<Generator*>();`

Comment: @slugonamission You were right.

Comment: @Deduplicator And how else should I initialise vector?

Comment: Seems you want it default-initialized, and that's what happens if you don't specify an initializer. Otherwise, on the declaration, with a possible override in the ctor-init-list. You are doing a move-assignment to the already initialized member in the ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoopGenerator` constructor is called in your code. The problem is on the side of debugger, which due to unknown reasons does not allow you to place breakpoint within the constructor. Output a log message in the constructor and you will see that it gets called.
BTW your line where you construct the object should be

```
LoopGenerator gen;
```

instead of

```
LoopGenerator gen = LoopGenerator();
```

(which is correct, but not idiomatic and not necessary). In the same way the statement

```
stripes = vector<Generator*>();
```

in the constructor is not necessary and may be omitted without changing your program meaning,

Comment: Or maybe it is optimized out. Or the omitted code means it's not actually called. Who knows, keep guessing.